# Web service is not working in post method

Tags: php, api, cron

I had written a simple script to display post values when calling the api. In request or get method it is displaying but in post method it is not displaying anything. Please help me. My code is :-

```
<?php

  echo "<pre>";
  print_r($_REQUEST);
  echo "--------POST Variables----------";
  echo "<pre>";
  print_r($_POST);


?>
```

Comment: Is this happening when you make a POST request with some parameters?

Comment: Are you sure there is `$_POST` data to display? Show us the output of `$_REQUEST` when you make a post request to this page

Comment: If it shows data when you fetch it with `$_GET`, you have a `get` request, not `post`

Comment: i tried passing parameters with DHC and postman and it is not working. Lastly, i tired with advanced rest client and in a wonder it got worked. Thank you all

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i tried passing parameters with DHC and postman and it is not working. Lastly, i tired with advanced rest client and in a wonder it got worked.

Answer (score 3):

first of all you can use below code to become sure about your request:

```
     if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST') {
     // echo something here
     }
```

are you now in if block??